# Keycloak / Angular ¿cual es la mejor manera de mostrar el nombre de usuario en mi app de Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, keycloak

```
   //Importamos el servicio
   import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

   //Creamos una variable a la que damos un valor provisional
   public username: string = "user1";

   //Inyectamos el servicio
   constructor(private keycloakService: KeycloakService){}

   //EN ngOnInit (ESTO FUNCIONA SOLAMENTE EN MOZILLA FIREFOX)

   let keycloakS = this.keycloakService.getKeycloakInstance();

   keycloakS.loadUserInfo().then(info => {
      console.log("Info del usuario: "+JSON.stringify(info));
      
      const stringifyprofile = JSON.stringify(info);
      const parseprofile = JSON.parse(stringifyprofile);
      this.username = parseprofile.preferred_username;

      }).catch(function(){
       console.log("ERROR al cargar los datos de usuario")
      });
     }
   }
```

No entiendo porque funciona solamente en Firefox y en el resto de navegadores (Chrome, Edge...) muestra error de CORS policy:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://...' from origin 'https://...' (son diferentes dominios) has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

¿Qué falta? ¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de guardar en la variable `username` el dato para poder hacer uso de él en el `template`?.

Comment: Pues así a grandes rasgos, falta que nos digas qué errores muestra en chrome, edge.. porque no veo ningún problema para que no funcione en todas partes. (Aparte de que trabajas con promesas y no con observables, pero bueno... las promesas siguen siendo usables en angular)

Comment: Buenas, acabo de editar la pregunta. Es error por política de CORS.

Comment: Entonces no tiene nada que ver con la librería ni con angular. En tu backend tienes que permitir las llamadas desde tu IP (normalmente, desde cualquier IP para que cualquier cliente se pueda conectar a tu API!). Si no, la mayoría de navegadores se negarán a comunicarse con tu API.